# alternative to sapply over strsplit of character vector

Tags: string, r, split

Imagine the following dataset (column vector):

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("AB3474","AB3482","AB3458","AB3487","AB3471","AB3452"))
df
       a
1 AB3474
2 AB3482
3 AB3458
4 AB3487
5 AB3471
6 AB3452
```

Now I want to build a new vector which gets values, that "a" has on the fifth position. So the resulting df should look like this:

```
df_new
       a new
1 AB3474   7
2 AB3482   8
3 AB3458   5
4 AB3487   8
5 AB3471   7
6 AB3452   5
```

I "sapplied" over the splitted string (using `sapply` and `strsplit`), but I guess there are simpler and hopefully faster ways for solving this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
df_new <- within(df, new <- substr(a, 5, 5))
```

Result:

```
       a new
1 AB3474   7
2 AB3482   8
3 AB3458   5
4 AB3487   8
5 AB3471   7
6 AB3452   5
```

EDIT: to answer the comment below:

```
within(df, new <- paste0(substr(a, 5, 5), ifelse(as.numeric(substr(a, 6, 6))>5, "b", "a")))
```

Result:

```
       a new
1 AB3474  7a
2 AB3482  8a
3 AB3458  5b
4 AB3487  8b
5 AB3471  7a
6 AB3452  5a
```

Note that `as.numeric` is preffered to avoid lexical comparisons.

Comment: thanks, and what if the last (6th) number has to be taken into account, too. for instance, if the last is > 5, then fifth value +b, else +a. so "new" would then get the values: 7a,8a,5b,8b,7a,5a. a and b can of course be replaced by anthing. it's just about the Problem described. maybe substr(substr())??

Answer (score 4):

If you have a *looooooooot* of rows maybe you will benefit from some `Rcpp` compiled code goodness. You could stick this in a file with the extension `.cpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string>

using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]

std::vector< std::string > extrC(CharacterVector x, int y) {
    int n = x.size();
    std::vector< std::string > out(n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      std::string tmp = Rcpp::as<std::string>(x[i]);
      out[i] = tmp[y-1]; //note the difference between indexing in R and C++ - C++ starts at 0!
    }
    return out;
  }
```

Then in R:

```
require(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("C:/path/to/file.cpp")
df$new <- extrC( df$a , 5 )
df
       a new
1 AB3474   7
2 AB3482   8
3 AB3458   5
4 AB3487   8
5 AB3471   7
6 AB3452   5
```

#### The idea

Take a character vector as input, and an integer for the position in each string you would like to extract a the value at. Return a `std::vector< std::string >` and let `Rcpp` handle wrapping of standard library objects to R objects. `std::string` objects have the `at` method which we can use to extract the desired character.

Note, this probably isn't very safe because we don't do any checking to see if the desired index actually falls *in* each character string.

Comment: I suspect this will be slower than the equivalent R code because you have to convert in and out of R's string class.

Comment: @hadley I just asked a question on R chat to this effect - I just did some benchmarking and found that to be the case. I am wondering if there is a way to avoid this (e.g. is there an `at()` method for R's string class?)

Comment: Not that I know of - generally R's internal string functions will be much faster than the Rcpp equivalents until someone spends a lot of time writing all the necessary shims.

Comment: @hadley stringrcpp?! :-)

Comment: @ Simon0101 Thanks for your answer. Fortunately, using substr was fast enough!

Comment: @Macs you are welcome. I actually found `substr`  to be faster than this anyway, but perhaps this isn't the *fastest* implementation.

Comment: @SimonO101 I did actually look into that, but it requires a lot more C++ skills than I have - the key to speed is avoiding those conversions.

Comment: @hadley Dirk whipped up something that doubles the speed of this by eliminating some unnecessary copying. it's in the r chat room at the mo, i'll edit it in later this eve for completeness.

Comment: If the downvoter would explain the downvote, that would be useful for me from a learning perspective. Thanks.